# Generate matrix from an index vector

Tags: matlab

In matlab, I have a matrix and index vector v (in real problem, v vector is very long)

```
A = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]; % 3-by-3 matrix
v = [1,2,3,2,3,3,1]
```

How can I generate a matrix like

```
[A(1,:);A(2,:);A(3,:);A(2,:);A(3,:);A(3,:);A(1,:)]
```

without using loop or write out everything explicitly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use vectors to index, `A([1,1,1])` would give you three times the first element.

```
A(v,:)
```